# Override third pary CSS propertise with in our CSS file

Tags: css

I have a third party CSS file, need to delete, add, override some properties. Meanwhile want to delete some classes without changes in the original one.

**e.g.**

**ThirdParty.css**

```
.cal_navline div
{
position: absolute;
top: 2px;
white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Is it possible to delete this class without changes within the original css file? Is it possible that above class is not treated or ignored in our code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to "delete" properties, you should use their *default* values.

You see, every property is **always** set, is just that they have default values.

For example, if you have an element with `position: absolute;` and you want to remove that, you would use `position: static !important;`, because the default value of `position` - that is, when is not set- is `static`.

The source about what I said about `position` is here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp

Read the part that says:

> **Default value:**    static

Same way, every css property has a default value. If you force the default value, is like deleting that property.

(`top`,`left`,`right`,`bottom` have `auto` as their default value, some others by default inherit the values of their parents, those have an `inherit` value as default, etc)

Here is a list with default css values: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/propidx.html

Comment: +1, If I have an option to vote multiple times, then I will vote you +5. :) cool solution.

Comment: @Suleman You are welcome! By the way, here is the list with the default css values straight from the w3: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/propidx.html

Comment: how we should handle the attributes that have empty default value? and we have to override them with default.

Comment: @Suleman what you mean with empty? you mean "none"? If is none or 0, just like that: `text-decoration: none !important` (`text-decoration` is one which default value is `none`) or you mean something else?

Comment: empty mean "not specified", e.g **border** does't have any default value.

Comment: Yes it does. `border` is just a shortcut to the other border related properties. According to the specs, border has as value: `[ <border-width> || <border-style> || 'border-top-color' ] | inherit`. If you check the individual default values of each, you'll see that something like `border: medium none <the value of your "color" property or the word "inherit">;` is pretty much what would be default. Yes, the "value of color" means that you have to manually set the same value as `color`. If the color is black, just doing `border: medium none black;`, or set the word '`inherit`'.

Comment: Ah but keep in mind some elements have a default border. like `<table>`. And that border value depends on the browser. If you open an html with a `<table>` and no css, you'll notice it does have borders. On chrome, you can use the "inspect element" tool, select the table's `<tr>`, click on `Computed Style` to see the values chrome asign by default.

Comment: Here is a fiddle with a table that has css manually specifying the same default values it would have if I have used no css, and used `<table border="1">` instead. Those are the default values chrome would give. (at least my chrome version) http://jsfiddle.net/nXsUz/

Answer (score 3):

You can use **!important** with a style to override a style.

You can use same class and style with !important which will override the styles.

Comment: Is it possible with any way that within our code, if we override the same class with empty properties then override the inner properties?

Comment: It will not override with CSS. Class with empty style is not having any effect.

Comment: Using !important you can override the value of an existing style with a different value.

Answer (score 1):

As the above answer, I would keep `!important` as the last option, if you want to override styles, you can use higher specificity rules like

```
.container_class .cal_navline div {
   position: absolute;
   top: 2px;
   white-space: nowrap;
}
```

If still it is not specific, you can use `!important` to override the third party CSS.

Also, you can use JS in this case if you are open to use it.

Comment: @Alien: I want to ignore all properties of the class that I want to override, Is it possible with any way?